# Azure JWT extra harcoded field for APP to APP autorization

Tags: azure

I have a main application (application A) and child applications (application B and C)

I want to use client_id and secret for B and C application with `scope` param to get token for application A (these part are working fine)

Now I want to add custom field into JWT token to add some data about applications B and C.

I am using python for connect to GraphAPI for creating and assign Policy for application

```
policy_definition = {
        "ClaimsMappingPolicy": {
            "Version": 1,
            "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true",
            "ClaimsSchema": [
                {
                    "Value": "application B",
                    "JwtClaimType": "application_code_name"
                }
            ],
        }
    }
```

These code are working fine and if I will assign these policy for application A I will be able to see my new field, but I want it to have different values for different applications (B and C)

So I am assigning these Policy for applications B and C and trying to add mappingPolicy after it and assign it for application A

```
policy_definition = {
        "ClaimsMappingPolicy": {
            "Version": 1,
            "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true",
            "ClaimsSchema": [
                {
                    "Source": "CustomClaimsProvider",
                    "ID": "application_code_name",
                    "JwtClaimType": "application_code_name"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But it's not working and I am not able to see new fields in JWT.

Maybe I am creating these Policies in wrong way? I am checking it by GET requests and I am able to see it, I am able to delete them, so I think the problem is in definition

Also I updated Manifest file and set Additional claim to true

I want get token by applications B and C for scope application A and be able to see custom field with hardcoded data in JWT fields list after decoding